# React Native JEST TDD - Cannot read property 'getByText' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-native, tdd

I have a inssue, with tdd. I want to call a event byText and i cant do that because i get this error in my component.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getByText' of undefined
```

this is my component:

```
const createSubject = props => {
    render(
      <AnnoucementItem
        {...defaultProps}
        {...props}
      />
    );
  };
```

and this is my test file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, fireEvent } from 'react-native-testing-library';
import Enzyme, { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

import i18n from '../../../../src/i18n';
import AnnoucementItem from '../../../../src/screens/Profile/AnnouncementList/AnnouncementItem';

jest.mock('react-redux');

let { onEdit, toggleVisibility, onDelete } = jest.fn();

describe('<AnnoucementItem />', () => {

  const defaultProps = {
    navigation: {},
    item: {
      id: 'annoucement id',
      user_id: 'id do usuario',
      is_published: true,
      images: {
        0: {
          secure_url: genericurl',
        },
      },
      address: {
        city: 'Pelotas',
        state: 'RS',
        number: '990',
        street: 'Rua Doutor Francisco Ferreira Veloso',
        neighbourhood: 'Py Crespo',
      },
      values: {
        other: '4.32',
        total: '4422.33',
      },
      positive_ratings: '2',
      negative_ratings: '1',
      onEdit: onEdit,
      toggleVisibility: toggleVisibility,
      onDelete: onDelete,
    },
    toggleVisibility: () => {},
    onDelete: () => {},
    onEdit: () => {},
    numberOfLikes: 3,
    SwitchOption: {
      switchValue: false,
    },

    userId: () => {},
    isFetching: () => {},
    shouldUpdate: () => {},
    userAnnouncements: () => {},
    formVisibility: () => {},
    error: () => {},

    fetchUserAnnouncements: () => {},
    deleteAnnouncement: () => {},
    fillFormAnnouncement: () => {},
    changeAnnouncementVisibility: () => {},
  };

  const createSubject = props => {
    render(
      <AnnoucementItem
        {...defaultProps}
        {...props}
      />
    );
  };

  describe('AnnoucementItem component', () => {
    it('should delete annoucement', () => {
      const { getByText, getByTextId } = createSubject();

      fireEvent.CallDelete(getByTextId('DeleteButton'),  'deleteAnnouncement');
      fireEvent.press(getByText(i18n.t('profile.announcementList.announcementItem.deleteAnnouncementAlert')));

      const {
        requestDeleteAnnouncement,
        successDeleteAnnouncement,
        announcementId,
      } = jest.fn();

      useDispatch.mockReturnValue(
        requestDeleteAnnouncement,
        successDeleteAnnouncement,
        announcementId);

      expect(AnnoucementItem.prototype.onDelete.calledOnce).toBe(true);

      expect(requestDeleteAnnouncement).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
        actionTypes: 'REQUEST_DELETE_ANNOUNCEMENT',
      });
      expect(successDeleteAnnouncement).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
        actionTypes: 'SUCCESS_DELETE_ANNOUNCEMENT',
        dispatch: { deletedId: announcementId },
      });
    });
  });

  it('should go to edit annoucement', () => {
    const { getByText, getByTextId } = createSubject();

    fireEvent.CallEdit(getByTextId('EditButton'),  'EditAnnouncement');
    fireEvent.press(getByText(i18n.t('profile.announcementList.announcementItem.editAnnouncement')));

    const editAnnouncement = jest.fn();
    const navigation = { navigate: jest.fn() };

    useDispatch.mockReturnValue(editAnnouncement);
    expect(editAnnouncement).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      navigation: { navigation },
    });
  });

  it('should count interested peoples in my annoucement', () => {
    const { getByText, item } = createSubject();

    const interested = getByText(item.positive_ratings + item.negative_ratings);

    expect(interested).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should switch visibleAnnoucement', () => {

  });
});
```

the question is, how can i get a element ByText?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your test update

```
const createSubject = props => {
    render(
      <AnnoucementItem
        {...defaultProps}
        {...props}
      />
    );
  };
```

to

```
const createSubject = props => {
    return render(
      <AnnoucementItem
        {...defaultProps}
        {...props}
      />
    );
  };
```

Since createSubject is a function you need to return something from that function in order to use its output.

Comment: thanks Jake <3 this was the result of a few hours of sleep and a lot of coffee

Comment: No problem!  If you could +1 & accept the answer, that would be great!

Comment: "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." :(